# How to integrate arduino board with apple home kit, Is it possible or not ?

Tags: ios, arduino, raspberry-pi, ios-homekit

I want to make my own ios app with homekit, which should control arduino, i have studied about homekit and i have doubt that whether it is possible to integrate arduino or raspberry PI with home kit or not ? any useful links ?

Comment: I don't know if you will get home kit running directly on an arduino but there are some open source projects that you can use as a bridge eg. https://github.com/brutella/hc

Comment: Thanks. can u have some other links containing a brief detail and example of home control , or kind of tutorials

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the arduino, the crypto behind the protocol is fairly complex and I'm not sure the processor could handle it well. I can find any sample projects out there either, but the Rasbery pi is another story. Since the Pi can run node, there is a node implementation of hap on github: https://github.com/KhaosT/HAP-NodeJS

I haven't used it, but it's fairly well documented. I doubt there are any tutorials available, I think these are fairly fringe projects at the moment, so you're going to have to get your hands dirty. Good luck.